# Call webservice from Sharepoint Designer 2013 Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am new to sharepoint designer and I just recently installed Sharepoint 2013 Designer studio on my machine. I was trying to create a workflow that calls a HTTP REST webservice. However, in my action list I do not see an option for Call Webservice. Any idea what I am doing wrong? I typed in Call in the step and still nothing was found.

[image]

Please, advice
Thanks,
Darcy

Answer (score 1):

Are you creating a **2013** workflow as the Call HTTP Webservice action is not available in 2010 workflows?

Answer (score 1):

As Fairfield alluded to, your screenshot depicts a SharePoint 2010 workflow and not a SharePoint 2013-style workflow, as evident by the missing 'Stage' button in the Ribbon as well as the absence of the 'Call HTTP Web Service' action.

Given the URL heading at the top of SharePoint Designer, this is in a SharePoint 2013 on-prem environment and so you will need to have a Workflow Manager farm set up and connected to your SharePoint server in order to have access to the SharePoint 2013-style workflows.